# How to use xargs to run bash -c on filenames with both single and double quotes

Tags: bash, escaping, xargs

I am trying to use `xargs` to run `ffmpeg` on every file in a folder and output the names of files that have vorbis audio.

I have come up with the following that mostly works, but it fails on files that have single quotes in the filename.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | onlyvideos | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -n1 -0 -I '{}' bash -c "if ( ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | grep Stream | grep -q vorbis ) ; then echo '{}' ; fi;"
```

`onlyvideos` is a script I have written that only prints the names of files with video extensions to stdout.

How can I get `xargs` to run `bash -c` on filenames that might include either or both single and double quotes?

Comment: Why would you use the custom script `onlyvideos` if `find` can do just that

Comment: also you should add `-print0` to `find` when using `xargs -0`

Comment: Because I don't want to have to manually list them every time: `String[] videoextensions = {"avi", "bdmv", "divx", "flv", "m2ts", "m4v", "mkv", "mp4", "mpg", "mpls", "vob", "webm", "xvid"};`. This is not really relevant to my question, but I've found my script very useful and use it all the time, in addition to my `onlymusic` script.

Comment: @suleiman True. That's also not really relevant to my question but my `onlyvideos` script doesn't currently support nulls as delimiters.

Comment: have you tried to remove double quotes from the `bash -c` cmd and use `$()` instead ?

Comment: @suleiman good idea. I just tried, not sure what's happening but it prints empty lines and doesn't seem to match anything? I think the `$()` is run in a separate shell and doesn't replace the `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this could be simplified a lot, probably, but if you want to stick with your `onlyvideos` script you could try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | onlyvideos | tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -n1 -0 bash -c 'if ( ffmpeg -i "$1" 2>&1 | grep Stream | grep -q vorbis ) ; then echo "$1" ; fi;' bash
```

Explanation: `bash -c 'cmd' arg0 arg1` executes `cmd` with position parameters set to `$0=arg0` (`bash` in our case) and `$1=arg1` (the file name in our case, passed by `xargs`). So, using `"$1"` in your command script `'cmd'` should work as you expect.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for that. How could it be simplified, just for my learning? Just a general explanation of how would be helpful. Do you just mean that I could use only `find -print0` with the actual video extensions instead of `onlyvideos` and the `tr`?

Comment: Yes, for instance. Or even better, write a new version of your `onlyvideos` script (e.g., `foo.sh`) that takes a single argument and prints it if and only if it was a video file with vorbis audio. Of course you can reuse your `onlyvideos` script in this new one. Then, just use `find` with the `exec` action: `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec ./foo.sh {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` style

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | onlyvideos | while read f; do if ( ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep Stream | grep -q vorbis ) ; then echo "$f" ; fi; done
```

Comment: Very tricky, seems there's more than one way to skin a cat! Thank you. This seems more readable as well.

Comment: Before using this you should carefully check your file names and your `onlyvideos` script. `while read f` does not preserve leading and trailing spaces, interprets backslashes, will split names containing newlines... (note that the `xargs`-based solution will also split names containing newlines). At least, it would probably be better to keep the `tr` substitution and use `while IFS= read -r -d''`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for the tip about `while read f`. I thought that the quotes would protect at least leading and trailing spaces. Bash seems so overcomplicated and dangerous just for escaping. So many gotchas and edge cases. It would be nice if you could declare strongly typed variables if you wanted.